# Contravariance usage in Scala

Tags: scala, covariant, contravariant

As per the definition of contravariance (super class instances will be accepted), my last statement in the below code snippet, should be accepted; but it is thrown with type error. Can you please correct my understanding.

```
  class A
  class B extends A
  class C extends B
  
  abstract class Box[-T] {
     def set(x : T) :Unit
  }
  
  val x = new Box[B] {
    def set(b:B) = Console println "B"
  }
  
  val y  = new Box[A] {
    def set(a:A) = Console println "A"
  }
  
  val z  = new Box[C] {
    def set(c:C) = Console println "C"
  }  

  x.set(new A)   <-- Type error
```

But  `x.set(new C)` is fine! So even though "contravariant parameters are accepted as method parameters" is in fact, are covariant parameters actually.

Comment: As the answers have pointed out, you are misunderstanding contravariance. Here's a snippet that does demonstrate it, given your example: `def foo(b: Box[B]) = b.set(new B);  foo(y) // prints A`

Comment: Notice that the results you're seeing are the same if you remove the `-` from `T`. What you're seeing has nothing to do with the variance setting of `T`.

Answer (score 2):

You are confusing how contravariance works. `x` is a **Box[B]** as such, `set` accepts values of type `B` *(or any subtype of `B` because that is what **Liskvo** says)*.

However, **Box[A]** is a *subtype* of a **Box[B]**. So you could have passed `y` where `x` is expected. Because a **Box** that can store any `A` can store a `B`.
But, a **Box** that can store only `B`s can not store and arbitrary `A`.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this not how it would work and that's from a conceptual stand point: a `B` is an `A` but not the other way around.

As indicated in the [scala doc for variances](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html#contravariances), contravariant type parameters allow to pass a "super-type" instead of the "sub-type", but this applies to what is used within the body (e.g. If the "super-type" already has defined what's used) otherwise I guess it just considers the type and we're back to what I explained before.